# How to place one element on top of another using flexbox?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, position

I'm trying to place text on top of an image. I want to achieve this using only Flexbox, without using the position property. Is it possible with Flexbox?

```
const Component = () => {
  return (
    <section>
      <img src={mountains} />
      <p className="paragraph">Hello everyone</p>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Component;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either u use a position property, or make the image as a div with background image

```js
    <div style={{backgroundImage: 'url("mountain.jpg")'}}> //Image link here
    <p className="paragraph">Hello everyone</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of absolute position within the flex container.
Thanks :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In css ia called "Hero image", you can do like this:

```
    <div style={{backgroundImage: 'url("image.jpg")',  backgroundPosition: "center", backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat", backgroundCover: "cover"}}>
        <p className="paragraph">Hello everyone</p>
    </div>
```

You can work with display flex inside of this div to change de "p" tag position.